# Automated transcripts of conference calls

Tags: software-recommendation

What's the best way to get an automated transcript of a FaceTime/Skype or simple audio conference call?

Comment: Do you have a Apple Mac Pro (12 Core) ?

Comment: Record the call and run it through Dragon Dictate?

Comment: There's lots of things you are asking people to cover here, and the question needs more info if you ask me.  Are you needing to record the conversations?  Are they already recorded?  Are you wanting to do it on the fly?  How much accuracy do you need?  What format do you need the output in, for example, and does it need the content splitting by speaker, timestamping, etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

A simple answer is NO.

There are lots of Dictation software but they really only work for Dictation (one person talking in a quiet room.

Even than you have to train the software to your specific voice and how you pronounce stuff to get accurate text output

You can try to use them for transcription a conference call, but you will end up editing a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As Buscar notes, even the best dictation software isn't really going to work for transcribing a conversation. However, you might want to read [this blog post](http://waxy.org/2008/09/audio_transcription_with_mechanical_turk/) by Andy Baio on how he uses Amazon's [Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/) to get transcriptions done cheaply.

The gist is, take your recording and chop it up into small chunks (he uses 5 minutes), and create Mechanical Turk jobs to transcribe each one. It's not free, but it looks like it's substantially cheaper than other paid transcription services, and the work of getting the recording onto the site could be automated relatively simply.